# How to clear google translate source text div using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a keyboard shortcut for running a **JS script** that opens `google translate` and translates the selected text.I want to clear previous word in source text in `google translate` every time run this script. What should I write for it in the last line?

```
document.execCommand('copy');
var googleTranslate;
if(googleTranslate == undefined)
    googleTranslate= window.open("https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fa&op=translate","Translate");
else
    googleTranslate.focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML markup for that section is

```
<textarea aria-label="Source text"
```

plus some other things, so the selector string

```
textarea[aria-label="Source text"]
```

will be able to select the element with JS, allowing you to clear its contents.

But if you're running your code from a domain other than `translate.google.com`, you won't be able to access the cross-origin window without some tweaks, due to security restrictions. Consider putting the code into a [userscript](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) instead, which automatically runs when `https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fa&op=translate` is accessed:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Clear GT
// @match            https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fa&op=translate
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelector('textarea[aria-label="Source text"]').value = '';
```